# Queries as SELECT statements with NOT EXISTS clauses

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, sqlplus

Table Position:

```
CREATE TABLE Position(
p#              NUMBER(8)       NOT NULL, /* Position number            */
ptitle          VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL, /* Position title             */
employer    VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL, /* Institution name           */
salary      NUMBER(9,2) NOT NULL, /* Salary         */
extras      VARCHAR(50)     , /* Extras         */
specification   LONG                , /* Specification      */
    CONSTRAINT Position_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( p# ),
    CONSTRAINT Position_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY ( ptitle )
                REFERENCES LPTitle ( title ) );

INSERT INTO Position VALUES ( 00000001, 'LECTURER', 'UNSW', 45000.00, 'computer', 'Teaching');
INSERT INTO Position VALUES ( 00000002, 'LECTURER', 'UOW', 45000.00, 'mouse pad', 'Research');
INSERT INTO Position VALUES ( 00000003, 'SENIOR LECTURER', 'UTS', 50000.00, NULL, 'A lot of hard work'  );
INSERT INTO Position VALUES ( 00000004, 'ASSOC. PROFESSOR', 'UOW', 60000.00, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO Position VALUES ( 00000005, 'PROFESSOR', 'UQ', 80000.00, 'chair', 'Research' );
INSERT INTO Position VALUES ( 00000006, 'PROFESSOR', 'UNSW', 80000.00, 'chair', 'Research' );
INSERT INTO Position VALUES ( 00000007, 'PROFESSOR', 'UOW', 80000.00, 'chair', 'Teaching and research');
```

I'm trying to find the title of the positions with the largest salary. In this case it should be 'PROFESSOR'. This is the query I came out with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ptitle
FROM
    Position
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT ptitle FROM Position WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Position)
        )
;
```

The result I get is 'no rows selected'. When I run just the sub-query I can get all the position titles except for the highest salary position:

```
SQL> SELECT ptitle FROM Position WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Position);

PTITLE                                                                                              
------------------------------                                                                      
LECTURER                                                                                            
LECTURER                                                                                            
SENIOR LECTURER                                                                                     
ASSOC. PROFESSOR
```

But whenever I run it as a sub-query in the NOT EXISTS query above I could not get back the position with highest salary. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery:

```
SELECT ptitle FROM Position WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Position)
```

always finds the same four rows, so at least one result is always returned, so `exists` would always be true, so `not exists` is always false. You have no correlation between the row you're examining and the subquery. If you do want a `not exists` then you need to include the row from the main table in the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ptitle
FROM
    Position pos1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT ptitle FROM Position pos2 WHERE pos2.salary > pos1.salary
        )
;
```

To use `max` you could check equality instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ptitle
FROM
    Position
WHERE
    salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Position)
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14688/2).

Or use an analytic function so you don't have to hit the table twice, as suggested elsewhere.

Comment: This is the kind of explanation I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to get the result you're looking for is to use an analytic function to `rank` all positions by salaries, and then just take the top one:

```
SELECT ptitle
FROM   (SELECT ptitle, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rk
        FROM   position)
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to know which part do I did wrong in my query. And I want to do it using NOT EXISTS clause.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost always a good idea to try to formulate the problem as exact as possible. In this case:

```
For what positions p1 does it not exist another position p2 such that that position has a 
higher salary.
```

Translating this into sql is now trivial:

```
SELECT distinct ptitle
FROM Position p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ptitle FROM Position p2 
    WHERE p2.salary > p1.salary
);
```

Did that clarify?